# Why method of current object in inner function is undefined?

Tags: javascript

In the outer function, this.foo is bar, that's what I expected. However, in the inner function, this.foo is undefined, which is very surprising. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function () {
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        (function () {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the outer function, this refer to myObject and therefore can properly reference and access foo.

In the inner function,which is a closure, though, this no longer refers to myObject. As a result, this.foo is undefined in the inner function (Prior to ECMA 5, this in the inner function would refer to the global window object; whereas, as of ECMA 5, this in the inner function would be undefined.)
    To fix this, we can store this in a local variable like self before reference it.

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function () {
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Comment: ES5 **strict mode** `undefined`, otherwise `window`.

Answer (score 0):

The first implementation is:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function () {
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        (function (self) {
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }(this));
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

The second implementation is:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function () {
        console.log("outer func: this.foo = " + this.foo);
        (function () {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        }.bind(this));
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Comment: Second one isn't really executed. You just bound it, and that's all.

Comment: Leo is right. Second one isn't executed. To execute it, just put () after it.

    var myObject = {
        foo: "bar",
        func: function () {
    console.log("outer func: this.foo = " + this.foo);
    (function () {
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
    }.bind(this)());
    }
    };
    myObject.func();

Comment: i missed brackets () ((