# Need help for output

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can anyone answer this?

What will the code below output to the console and why?

```
(function(){    
  var a = b = 3;    
})();
console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));    
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

What will the code below output to the console and why?

```
var myObject = { 
    foo: "bar",    
    func: function() {    
        var self = this;    
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);    
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);    
        (function() {    
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);   
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo); 
        }());    
    }    
};    
myObject.func();
```

Comment: `What will the code below output to the console` have you tried running it?

Comment: For the First one: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329444/why-a-is-undefined-while-b-is-3-in-var-a-b-3) Second one: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310385/why-method-of-current-object-in-inner-function-is-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Code:**

```
(function(){    
  var a = b = 3;    
})();
console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));    
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

**Output:**

```
a defined? false
b defined? true
```

**Explaination:**
Here you are using Immediately Invoked function Expression(IIFE). Here `a` is declared inside function's scope but `b` is not declared due to which it gets registered to the global scope. Now since you are accessing `a` and `b` outside in the global scope `a` is `undefined` but `b` is `defined`.

**Second Code:**

```
var myObject = { 
    foo: "bar",    
    func: function() {    
        var self = this;    
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);    
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);    
        (function() {    
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);   
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo); 
        }());    
    }    
};    
myObject.func();
```

**Output:**

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

**Explaination:**

The key here is `this` reference inside a function which is an object's property is that object itself. So first two `logs` print the expected result. Then you are using an IIFE and `this` reference inside IIFE is the `global Object(Window object)`. Therefore `this.foo` means `Window.foo` there which is `undefined`. However `self` is accessable inside that function which has value equal to that object. Hence it prints the `foo` variable.

Comment: Thx for this answer what im looking for :)

Comment: Can you please explain _why_ `this` of the nested function refers to the Window object instead of the `this` object of its parent function from where it was immediately invoked?

Answer (score 4):

**First part** of your code is equivalent to this.

```js
(function(){
  var a;
  b = 3;
  a = b;
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));

console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

In this case `a` is declared in the current function, related to the current scope and is not visible outside of it's scope. So it is `undefined` in the outer scope. But `b` is declared as a global variable, so it is visible everywhere and it is not `undefined`, its value is `3`.

**What about the last code part**, each function has it's own context, to which `this` refers. For first level functions, which are also called methods in some programming languages, `this` refers to the current object for which it is called. But for the inner function declared inside the `func`, it has it's own context, to which `this` refers. So why `this` refers to `undefined` - not the the object. But with another variable like `self` which is declared in the outer scope of that function, you can access the outer variable. The key part is related to the variable with name `this`. This is special.

```js
var myObject = { 
    foo: "bar",    
    func: function() {    
        var self = this;    
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);    
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);    
        (function() {    
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);   
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo); 
        }());    
    }    
};    
myObject.func();
```

Comment: Yes thats same but i want to know the output

Comment: Just run and see the output

Answer (score 1):

The below code is a n immediately invoking function
The scope of the variable `a` & `b` is inside the function , but `console.log` is outside the `function` , So they will undefined

```
console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined')); //output a defined false
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined')); //output b defined? true
```

```js
(function() {
  var a = b = 3;
})();
console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

Have added comment to the below snippet, hopefully it will be useful

```js
var myObject = {
  foo: "bar",
  func: function() {
    // here this & self will refer to the myObject
    var self = this;
    console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo); //outer func:  this.foo = bar    
    console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo); //outer func:  self.foo = bar    
    (function() {
      // here self will refer to the myObject context where as 
      // this will refer to window object.
      // In window foo is not defined, so it will give undefined
      console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo); //inner func:  this.foo = undefined  
      console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo); //inner func:  self.foo = bar
    }());
  }
};
myObject.func();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = { 
    foo: "bar",    
    func: function() {    
        var self = this;    
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);       
        (function() {    
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);   
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo); 
        }());    
    }    
};    
myObject.func();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).